# Monitoring android processes

Tags: android, process

I am working on a project in which monitoring of the processes is required (Creation of the process...). Currently we can get all the running processes from the API [ActivityManager::getRunningAppProcesses()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses()).

But calling the above API every few seconds (Polling) is not an efficient way. Is there any way in the android system through which we will get intimated about the create of new app process? Any information or guidance will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that by monitoring the zygote task we will be able to monitor the creation of new process.

Monitor "/proc/ZygotePid/task" folder. But this will not give us when already created app(process) is brought foreground. This will give only information about creation of new process.

Replace ZygotePid with actual pid of the zygote in your system. Since every process is created by ZygotePid, getting the parent process id in your application will give you the ZygotePid